# Viewing logs of a specific Windows service

Tags: windows-7, services

I have created a Windows service that is supposed to start a certain Java process but something is wrong and the process does not start. Does this service generate any log that I can read in order to understand what's wrong?

I tried looking into Windows Event Viewer but it does not look like starting/stopping this service results in any events.

I created the service using this batch file:

```
@echo off
TITLE "Installing Service"

set "INSTALL_HOME=%~dp0"

REM export environment variables 
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"

instsrv.exe Node "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe"
reg import "%INSTALL_HOME%\Node.reg"
echo "Install Complete"
pause
```

And the `Node.reg` looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Node\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\\temp\\start_node.bat"
"AppDirectory"="C:\\temp"
"AppParameters"="> C:\\temp\\logs\\srvany.log 2>C:\\temp\\logs\\srvany.error.log"
```

Please not that there are no principal problems with the way I install this service as it works fine on my other machines.